# Configuration ODBC for MySQL in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need help to finish the configuration of ODBC for MySQL in Windows. I am receiving different errors, and I have tried several options, but nothing is working. I really appreciate your help.

So basically, we are using **MySQL** for **CiviCRM** on **Druppal**. In order to access the database online, we use two sets of user/password, one for accessing the phpMyAdmin console, and the other one to access the database itself.

I want to configure the ODBC connection so the users could get the information directly in their computers.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. I installed the ODBC Driver: "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver" 32 bits.
2. I went to the ODBC administration console and configure one system DNS using this driver.
3. I get the TCP/IP Server directly from the Database Server Information in our phpMyAdmin, and initially I 3306 port.
4. I type our user for the database (not for phpMyAdmin) and I tested the connection without password. Although it is successful, I just get the databases: information_schema and test, the name of our database is not in the options.
5. Later I typed our password, and try the connection again, but I get this error:

> "Access denied for user USERNAME@LocalHost (Using password: YES)"

In the console I could see that the username is `USERNAME@127.0.0.3` and not `localhost`.

6. I tried changing port to 3307 because I read somewhere, that it was a possible solution. But I got this error: `Can not connect to MySQL Server on ServerName (10061)`.

Obviously I am not an expert on this matter. I would appreciate your help to configure effectively the ODBC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would get back to port 3306 with a mysql daemon restart.

Run thru some of the tests I typed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322375/1816093) at the bottom under the section Why Can't I connect. Look at hostnames.

and the query `select user,host,password from mysql.user`. You will also see Grants, etc. The grants suggest why your dbname is not seen. There are always a few moving parts to these problems. The fact that you are on 3307 now adds another wrinkle.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did not change the port in MySQL, I just use another port in the parameter of the ODBC on Windows. I can not make any change in the Database itself, what I want to get (and I do not know how) is that the user that the ODBC use is USERNAME@127.0.0.3 instead of USERNAME@Local_Host. I could log on online in the database with USERNAME@127.0.0.3, so it should work for the ODBC as well, but I do not have idea which parameter should I change in the ODBC to get that. Do you know, how I could do that? Thanks in advance.